# Fear of smart people/ phobia of intelligence

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes: having a strong fear of smart people.

I tried to look up "phobia of intelligence", "fear of smart people" etc. but couldn't find anything.

> He has/is __________

Comment: What about a weak fear? He is intelligence averse.

Comment: The closest you can come is probably the fear of knowledge. (*Gnosiophobia* or *epistemophobia*.)

Comment: You can add phobia to generally anything and people will know what you mean.

Comment: @user47014 Which is why *smartypantsophobia* is the new *bête noire* of our day.

Comment: @tchrist cool that's all new to me, I will start using that

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica Smells answerish.

Comment: An American politician.

Comment: Fear of wisdom would be _sophophobia_, which sounds a bit like the person is afraid of the couch.

Answer (score 1):

Invented-Greek **epistemonophobia** (επιστημονοφοβία *epistēmonophobia*, pronounced "e.pis.tee.mo.no.pho.bi.a"), from Modern Greek [επιστήμονας *epistēmonas*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AE%CE%BC%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%82#Greek) "scientist"

Or specifically **epistemonissophobia** (επιστημόνισσοφοβία *epistēmonissophobia*), from [επιστημόνισσα *epistimónissa*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BC%CF%8C%CE%BD%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%83%CE%B1#Greek) "*female* scientist".

Or generically **epistemophobia** (επιστημοφοβία *epistēmophobia*), from Ancient Greek [ἐπιστήμη *epistḗmē*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AE%CE%BC%CE%B7#Greek) (pronounced "e.pis.tee.mo.pho.bi.a") "science, knowledge", from  ἐπίσταμαι *epístamai* "to know, to have the knowledge of something".

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a fear of a kind of person not fear of knowledge per se, how about something like scholarphobia?  It doesn't have the same delightful ring of smartypantsophobia, but it could be a useful understated synonym.

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U. I recommend that you try to see if there's a dictionary entry for your word, which you can link here. Answers are supposed to be backed up with sources here.